# Kendo ui grid dropdownlist populate object object

Tags: cakephp, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I am trying to implement Cakephp kendo ui grid dropdownlist to edit colum `partner_type_id` but stuck cause dropdownlist populate `[object][object]`.

This is my code :

```
$(function() {
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        batch: true,
        pageSize:10,        
        transport: {
            read: {
                url:"<?php echo $this->Html->url('/Partners/get_partner',true)?>",
                dataType:"json",
            }
        },
        schema: {
            id:"Partner.id",
        }
    });     

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,             
        columns: [
            { field: "Partner.name"},
            { field: "Partner.partner_type_id", 
             template: "#: PartnerType.name #", editor: categoryDropDownEditor
            },
            { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "182px" }
        ],
        toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel","destroy"],
        height: 400,
        navigatable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes:true
        },
        editable:"inline" ,    
        filterable: {
            extra: false,
            operators: {
                string: {
                    startswith: "Starts with",
                    eq: "Is equal to",
                    neq: "Is not equal to"
                }
            }
        },       
    });      

    function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input required required data-text-field="PartnerType.name" data-value-field="Partner.id" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url:"<?php echo $this->Html->url('/Partners/get_partner_type',true)?>",
                        dataType:"json",
                    }    
                },
            },
        });
    }      
});
```

as you know that I use nested JSon, is it problem? I have tried using native PHP and MySql (flat Json) with the same code and work well.

/Partners/get_partner return below :
[ { "Partner":{"id":"1","name":"King James","partner_type_id":"2"}, "PartnerType":{"id":"2","name":"Vendor"} } ]

/Partners/get_partner_type' return below:
[ {"PartnerType":{"id":"1","name":"Customer"}}, {"PartnerType":{"id":"2","name":"Vendor"}} ]

Anybody would share?

Comment: Could you show an example of what is your dropdown list service returning?

Comment: Here is the screenshot : http://s807.photobucket.com/user/excelf/media/screenshots/d224cabf-8694-4c22-9888-367e21014b26.png.html

Comment: What I meant is the JSON... If you open ".../Partners/get_partner_type" in your browser, what does the JSON looks like? My theory, is that problem is the structure of the JSON that is not just an array of strings but objects. *BUT* in the DataSource definition you are not specifying neither [dataTextField](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/dropdownlist#configuration-dataTextField) nor [dataValueField](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/dropdownlist#configuration-dataValueField) so KendoUI is not able to display the right information

Comment: [
  {
    "Partner":{"id":"1","name":"King James","partner_type_id":"2"},
    "PartnerType":{"id":"2","name":"Vendor"}
  }
]

[
   {"PartnerType":{"id":"1","name":"Customer"}},
   {"PartnerType":{"id":"2","name":"Vendor"}}
]

Comment: Your JSON is not valid, you returning two arrays instead of one. Could you check your service?

Comment: Ow..it separate json. i mean the first is for read and the last for dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having filed name mis-match issue
the editor name should match with the grid field name
in your case the field is

Patner { 
           PatnerId,
          PatnerName;
}

So make this consistent through your code as below other wise editor column will keep display [object object] beacuse it could not find the right property name

```
$(function() {
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
   batch: true,
     pageSize:10,       
     transport: {
         read: {
                url:"<?php echo $this->Html->url('/Partners/get_partner',true)?>",

                dataType:"json",
         }

     },

schema: {

  id:"PartnerID",
  Patner: { defaultValue: { PartnerID: 1, PatnerName: "Jhon Doe"} }


}
```

});

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: dataSource,               
    columns: [

    { field: "Partner.PatnerName"},
    { field: "Partner", 
         editor: categoryDropDownEditortemplate: "#= Partner.PatnerName #"
    },
    { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "182px" },

 ],

function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input required required data-text-field="PatnerName" data-value-field="PartnerID" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: {

                transport: {
                     read: {
                            url:"<?php echo $this->Html->url('/Partners/get_partner_type',true)?>",
                            dataType:"json",
                      }    
                },


            },

        });
}
```

Comment: [
  {
    "Partner":{"id":"1","name":"King James","partner_type_id":"2"},
    "PartnerType":{"id":"2","name":"Vendor"}
  }
]

Comment: [
   {"PartnerType":{"id":"1","name":"Customer"}},
   {"PartnerType":{"id":"2","name":"Vendor"}}
]

Answer (score 0):

In a kendo grid with an editable dropdownlist, the problem is with the value of the dropdownlist field in the datasource of the grid. (Not the datasource of the dropdownlist).

If the value of the field is null, it displays [object Object] when you try to edit it.

I resolved it by setting a default value for the field (if null), when filling the datasource.

SELECT
 Column1,
 Column2, 
 ISNULL(ParterName, '') AS ParterName
FROM TableName